# How to find/import javascript module from Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I added [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) to my package.json and in a file I am trying to use it, so I have the following line.

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
```

I get `Cannot find module 'dom-to-image'` on this line, so I am not certain how to import a javascript library.

In my node_modules directory I have the library.

Comment: You first must register the module in app.module in imports, with the signature import {domtoimage} from 'dom-to-imange'  and you can use the library

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run a new npm install, then the syntax should pick it up.

Just a heads up, when you do the document.getbyId make sure to prepend it with the right tag, ie: document.getElement...